# Is it possible to load huge number of users in Visual Studio Load Test and check database hits for all the users simultaneously?

Tags: visual-studio, performance-testing, database-performance, sqlperformance

I was load testing a web application with Visual Studio Load Test. While performing test, I am unable to load multiple users. My need is, if I load 100 users virtually (in localhost) in my load test, I need database entries of that 100 users after the load test finished. If I set load test time to 5 minutes, the 100 user load test should complete in time and I could see the database has those 100 user's action data. Is this possible and if please explain ? Thank you.

Comment: I think the answer to your question is: yes. However this question is so vague that I am not sure what you are asking. Please read the help information (linked from the top of every Stackoverflow page) on how to write a good, clear, question.

Comment: Thank you AdrianHHH, I have edited the question. Can you please help me now ?